# Network architecture of AlphaZero

Tags: machine-learning

I am curious about the network architecture of [AlphaZero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlphaZero). Can anybody tell me details about it? Is it the same as in AlphaGo Zero?

Comment: It is not described in the research paper about AlphaZero!

Answer (score 1):

The AlphaGo Zero paper tests a few different architectures:

1. Seperate 12-convolutional-block policy and value networks (as in AlphaGo)
2. A single 12-convolutional-block network with dual policy and value outputs
3. Separate 20-residual-block networks
4. A single 20-residual-block network with dual policy and value outputs
5. A single 40-residual-block network with dual policy and value outputs

In the [AlphaZero](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01815) paper AlphaZero Go wins 60 games in a 100-game match against the 20-block single resnet AlphaGo Zero, but it is not explicitly stated which architecture AlphaZero is using. It is either the 40-block single resnet since this was the best, or it is the 20-block single resnet in order to make a fair comparison with AlphaGo Zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me where you found this information and which network was finally used?

Comment: You know, I am not sure anymore. I re-read the paper and it is surprisingly ambiguous. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I think it is not clear from the paper "Mastering Chess and Shogi by Self-Play with a General Reinforcement Learning Algorithm". But in the prior paper about AlphaGo Zero ("Mastering the Game of Go without Human Knowledge") they wrote on page 6:
"... Parameters were updated from 700,000 mini-batches of 2,048 positions. The neural network contained 20 residual blocks (see Methods for further details)."

So, if they used the same architecture as for AlphaGo Zero, it was probably 20 residual blocks...